# The NoiseSynth in Tone.js makes no sound

Tags: javascript, tone.js

The [NoiseSynth](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r13/NoiseSynth) of [Tone.js](https://tonejs.github.io/) isn't making any noise

I'm trying to learn Tone.js but when I try to play a sound with the NoiseSynth it doesn't make a noise.
Am I missing something?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/13.0.1/Tone.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">TCHSSS</button>
```

```
var noiseSynth = new Tone.NoiseSynth().toMaster();
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    noiseSynth.triggerAttackRelease('8n');
});
```

I expected this to make a white noise of the length of an 8th note.
but it doesn't do anything. 
[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zbna89v/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with NoiseSynth on the version of Tone.js that you're using. Works with tone@13.4.9 instead of tone@13.0.1

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/13.4.9/Tone.min.js"></script>
```

Modified jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yotammann/xjtL19u5/